# why is steam showing me "waiting for network" always?

Tags: networking, 22.04, launcher, games, steam

[i changed my network and tested them and wait about 10h for each of them but it show me this again and again][1]

**strong text**
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LXmC.png